# Facebook Graph API 3.0 - Get public figure's posts (app review?)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on a university course project, analyzing Facebook posts by a public figure. Graph API used to return such posts, but now:

```
"message": "(#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this 
endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public 
Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable 
features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review.",
```

However, the application process for 'Page Public Content Access' seems to assume I'm a business, building an app to interact with users, which I'm not. So I don't have a "Privacy Policy" and app logo and such, because there are no "users" in my case. Does any one know of some (alternative) method for getting the public posts (e.g. good scraper?) or some API method not requiring the review process or some other suggestions?

Comment: I have same problem, did you find solution? I tried to Review but they denied because "Page Public Content Access" is for login interactions etc. 
I